# add html content to hidden form field

Tags: html, forms, cdata

Is it possible to pass a chunk of html content to a hidden field and how would I do this?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - simply [HTML encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) the content (e.g. replace "<" with "&lt" etc...)

You didn't specify which language you'll use for poplulating the field value, so I can't help with details of how to encode.

Here's a [reference of how to do it in jQuery](http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb).

[Here's Java](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_perform_HTML_entity_encoding_in_Java#Libraries)

Comment: OK - define irony... 3 hours after I answeed this, I had an urgent ticket which ended up being caused by a legacy bug whose origin was - guess it - need to HTML encode strings :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Javascript:

```
<input type="hidden" id="htmlCodes" />
```

```
document.getElementById("htmlCodes").value = "<strong>Hello World</strong>";
```

Just be sure that your values are properly-escaped when you pass them into the hidden form field.

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/ubofu/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can also "spawn" a hidden textarea after processing the content inside.

This can be done easily with Jquery :

```
$('#your_form')
.append('<textarea name="content" class="hidden">' + your_content + '</textarea>');
```

Here we assuming that you've got a "hidden" class, Bootstrap's got one, but you can also use this :

CSS Code :

```
.hidden 
{ 
  display: none !important ; 
  visibility: hidden !important; 
}
```