# Syntax of putting value in hidden field to be used by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hidden-field

I have a hidden field and I want to html in that.
This html is letter used by the jQuery.
The value is like

```
 <input type='hidden' class='hid_multitag' 
    value='<ul><li onclick ='return addCrmTagCode("test")'>test123</li>
               <li onclick ='return addCrmTagCode("abc")'>abc123</li>
           </ul>'
 />
```

But the problem is with single quotes. How can I put this in a hidden filed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want set value of hidden field with another html ??

Comment: Why you are put html in hidden field value.You can easily store on some other controls like `div` `p` etc and make it `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

**I think you will have your answer** ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364612/add-html-content-to-hidden-form-field)***

Or you can alternatively put it inside some HTML element like div and **set its style to display:none;** and later on retrieve it through script.

Answer (score 1):

use a div instead of a hidden field and `display:none` the `div`

```
<div class='hid_multitag' style="display:none;">
    <ul>
       <li onclick ='return addCrmTagCode("test")'>test123</li>
       <li onclick ='return addCrmTagCode("abc")'>abc123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```